# Safest way to include/embed third party javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day all,
I've recently taken over a website that has about 10 third party javascripts embeded into each page load.  These include but are not limited to analytics, chat system, A/B testing, reviews, fonts, product recommendations, libraries (jquery) and custom code for the site.  Some of these are hosted locally, many are hosted by the company that created them.

Can I get some input on the best way to load all these and allow them all to function 100% properly but prevent them from causing delays for my visitors.

I found two solutions that seemed promising but have not heard anything about them / used them so I reluctant to implement.  I would appreciate any thoughts/help.  Thanks!!!

http://www.olark.com/spw/2011/10/lightningjs-safe-fast-and-asynchronous-third-party-javascript/

[Detecting and terminating slow third party javascript requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073346/detecting-and-terminating-slow-third-party-javascript-requests) [ http://headjs.com/ ]

Comment: It depends. Combine the ones that it makes sense to combine, and leave the others alone. Move them all to before the closing body tag so that the content of the page won't be delayed by loading javascript. Here's a related article: [High Performance Web Sites: Rule 9  Reduce DNS Lookups](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydnfiveblog/high-performance-sites-rule-9-reduce-dns-lookups-7207.html) **TLDR**: splitting the files among multiple hosts allows for parallel downloads, however, it increases the number of dns lookups that may have to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For asynchronously loading javascript, you can use the HTML5 async attribute

```
<script async src="http://third-party.com/resource.js"></script>
```

You can also use the classic way but it's less recommended nowadays.

```
(function(d, t) {
    var g = d.createElement(t),
        s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.src = '//third-party.com/resource.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
}(document, 'script'));
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a nice blog post](https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/) on the `async` subject

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways for that: Either add the `async=true` parameter to the script tag, or do as Google recommends - move the reference beyond the screen fold of your text, ideally to the foot.

Firefox has this useful Browser Console which shows some sources of delays. You'll likely have to make compromises and give up some of the hogs anyway.

If you haven't done it already, enable HTTP compression, especially for .js files. Curiously, this helps even on LAN where the connection doesn't *seem* to limit things.